# Get __FILE__ of compiled script

Tags: file, crystal-lang

How can I get the compiled version of my Crystal script to get its own __FILE__. Here is an example. I have a file called ~/test.cr with the following contents:

```
puts __FILE__
```

I compile the script via Crystal

```
~$ crystal ~/test.cr -o ~/test.compiled
```

Next I run ~/test.compiled. I produces the result

```
/Users/Account1/test.cr
```

even though the __FILE__ is actually

```
/Users/Account1/test.compiled
```

Is there a way to make it produce

```
/Users/Account1/test.compiled
```

Instead of

```
/Users/Account1/test.cr
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meta constant `__FILE__` always point to the source file, not the executable. However, you can use `$0` to get the current executable path (or the full path using `File.expand_path`):

foo.cr:

```
puts $0
puts File.expand_path($0)
```

Then compile and execute:

```
$~ crystal build foo.cr
$~ ./foo
./foo
/Users/MyUser/foo
```

Comment: Also, `$0` is an alias for `PROGRAM_NAME` which is larger to type but more descriptive